# Pandas.rolling_apply will multithread on my laptop but not on virtual server

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, virtual-machine

I have a pandas.rolling_apply on a large dataframe that calls a custom function to do a regression and return a single number.

On my laptop (Windows 7 Home Premium, Intel Core i7-4700MQ) it happily utilises 4 cores (50% CPU usage, i7-4700MQ has 4 processors and 8 logical cores).

The exact same code on a virtual server (Windows server 2012 R2 Std, Intel Xeon E5-2680 v2) only appears to use 1 core (13% CPU usage, 2 sockets, 8 virtual processors).

Can anyone shed some light on how the multi-threading in pandas works, why usage of cores is 50% on my laptop and 13% on the server, and if there are any ways to increase the core usage (and speed?).

Comment: A tip from a colleague of mine: 
I would hazard a guess it is trying to detect hyper threads to avoid running in to itself effectively trying to run two threads on the same core. As ESX is much more effective at managing this and your VM has access to 8 physical cores (albeit through a virtualised layer managed by ESX) I would see if there is a way to try and turn off this detection of virtual cores if possible.

Comment: Is everything fitting in memory on both machines or is it possible that the VM is using less CPU because it's having to read from disk?

Comment: It's all in memory in both cases.